# YouTube video in UIWebView isn't centered

Tags: ios, youtube, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` in Storyboard that has proper constraints.
Here is the code:

`youtubeView` is this:

```
@IBOutlet var youtubeView: UIWebView!
youtubeView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
youtubeView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(youtubeView.frame.width)\" height=\"\(youtubeView.frame.height)\" src=\"\(youtubeUrl)?&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)
```

The problem is that I get something like this: [simulator screenshot](http://prntscr.com/9njdek)

Can you help me centering YouTube video inside this `UIWebView`?

Comment: vertically or horizontally centered?

Answer (score 0):

Better to use a full screenshot. Have no clue of the overall vertical position, i.e. anything below that.

1. Make sure to constraint your `UIWebView` correctly, because I can't tell what's the `size` of your web view. Either align center with `y` axis of the superview, or fill the gap with `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` set to `0`.
2. If the `UIWebView` is already constraint as above, then it's really a `HTML/CSS` question. To center horizontally, use margin property. `style="margin: auto;"` Alternatively,  `width=100%` in your case is also fine. If not center vertically, try with simple solution like wrapping a `div` with `display: inline-block;` style.

Comment: I have edited the post, please see again. (screenshot changed)

Answer (score 0):

What I did was a bit of a hack, not the real solution. I've set constraints to be a negative number, so definitely **not** the best practise. If someone comes up with a better one, please let me know.

Comment: Please show the constraint you set for the `UIWebView`

Comment: As I suggested in my answer, your problem is not center youtube, but center the web view. If you want to fix width and height of your webview, then align the center with superview's center axis. Rather than use set any spacing like leading.

Comment: @zcui93 i've done everything you said, nothing helped

Comment: I saw nothing close to my suggestion from your constraint screenshot, so I can't help. Use either center constraint + fixed width, or use leading = trailing = 0 to center. Go and read more auto-layout.

Comment: yeah, i will definitely do so. need more expirience in that field. anyway, thank @zcui93 !

Comment: My final try. Remove all constraints, and just set leading and trailing to superview = 0, i.e. left and right, you will see it center horizontally. **Or** leave the width constraint and remove others, set center constraint to align with center y axis of superview, you will also see it center horizontally. You can do similar things to the vertical ones.